# delete data in datagridview from database

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Below is the code that I use to delete data in a datagridview from my database, but I'm encountering an error:

[image]

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Try
        con.Open()
        For i As Integer = Me.DataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
            CmdDelete = "DELETE rsdcpatienttbl WHERE TreatmentCount='" & Me.DataGridView1.SelectedRows(i).Cells(0).Value.ToString() & "'"
            adapter = New MySqlDataAdapter(CmdDelete, con)
            ds = New DataSet()
            adapter.Fill(ds)
            Me.DataGridView1.Rows.Remove(Me.DataGridView1.SelectedRows(i))

        Next
        load_table()

        MessageBox.Show("Deleted Successfully.", "Informed", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
    Catch ex As Exception

        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString())
    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: It's not clear what exactly you want to delete. Do you want to delete the record from your database or just remove the row from `DGV`, or both?

Comment: i want both actually

Answer (score 0):

if you using `MySqlDataAdapter` to perform the operation then you do not need to open the connection sepratly, remove `con.Open()` to skip the exception you are getting

Comment: if i remove con.open() in the code, it says "Successfully Deleted" but it does not do it's job to delete